# Unable to import Haskell packages in the "user" package database

Tags: haskell, cabal, ihaskell

Is there something I need to do to enable import of Haskell packages from the `user` package database?

While most apps and tools on my system (GHC, GHCi, Cabal, Stack, my IDE, etc.) seem to be aware of both the `global` and `user` package databases by default. Ask least some — [e.g., IHaskell](https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell/issues/581) — is unable to import any packages in my `user` package database.

Is there something I can do globally to my Haskell/GHC installation so that my `user` packages are visible to all Haskell tools and applications I install?

---

I'm using Homebrew Haskell on OS X 10.11, and have the package databases in the standard locations:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.10.2/lib/ghc-7.10.2/package.conf.d
```

and

```
/Users/Rax/.ghc/x86_64-darwin-7.10.2/package.conf.d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [an error specific to IHaskell](https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell/issues/581#issuecomment-145932645), which will be addressed in a future release.